# Is there a lightweight way to customize the devInteractions views without fully setting up a server?

Tags: openid-connect, node-oidc-provider, oidc-provider

We're currently using `node-oidc-provider` to make a mock local OIDC provider.

I'd like to make the login page look/behave more like our actual production login provider. Ultimately, my goal is to be able to write Cypress automation that works the same whether running locally or remotely, with no `if (isLocal)` type diverging behavior.

However, I want this to be as lightweight as possible, not fully set up a Koa server, etc. Basically, I just want to customize `lib/views/login.js` without extensive configuration beyond that.

I can't find anything in the docs to do something like this - even their standalone example has a bunch of Koa files beyond the views themselves (like example/routes/koa.js). This seems a bit... heavy... considering all I want is to customize the html a little, not change routes, etc.

Am I stuck with fully customizing a server (or doing something weird, like mucking with `node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/views/login.js`) if I want something like this?

Honestly, the minimal version of what I need is just inserting a `data-test` property on the 'login' input. Ideally, also removing the password input, but as long as it accepts blank for that, doesn't matter.